# Coldfusion 2016 how to include template when using cfscript mail()?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-2016

A simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish using tag based code:

```
<cfmail
   to="someone@x.com"
   from="someone@y.com"
   subject="howdy"
   type="html">
      <cfinclude template="path/to/emailtemplates/sometemplate.htm"/>
</cfmail>
```

I've tried all manner of solutions using cfscript and am at a roadblock.  I thought this might do it, but alas no.

```
savecontent variable="mailBody" {
  include "path/to/emailtemplates/sometemplate.htm";
};
mail = new mail();
mail.setTo( "someone@x.com" );
mail.setFrom( "someone@y.com" );
mail.setSubject( "howdy!" );
mail.setType( "HTML" );
mail.setBody( mailBody );
mail.send();
```

We're not sending multi-part e-mails - just HTML.  Is there a way to do this in script?

Comment: What is happening when you run that code? Is an error being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that, in `cfinlcude` you will not be able to include an `HTML` file. Looks like you are going to need the help of `FileRead()` function instead of include.

`mailBody=FileRead('absolute/path/to/emailtemplates/sometemplate.htm' [, charsetIfNeeded]);`

For `FileRead` to work you should provide an absolute path to an on-disk or in-memory text file on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this answers the initial question but fyi in coldfusion 10 I used to be able to tell CF to process other files than cfm. In your application use this line:

```
<cfset THIS.compileextforinclude = "htm" />
```